# Running a few java applications with total heap size memory set to more than phisycal memory

Tags: java, memory-management

Imagine I have a **64-bit** machine with the total amount of memory (physical + virtual) equal to **6 GB**. Now, what will happen when I run 5 applications with `-Xmx2048m` at the same time? They won't fail on start since this is 64-bit OS but what will happen when they all will need to use the 2GB of memory which I've set for them?

**Question:** Is it possible that there will be some memory leaks or something? What will happen? What are possible consequences of doing that?

I've read those questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949904/why-am-i-able-to-set-xmx-to-a-value-greater-than-physical-and-virtual-memory-on) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648454/what-happens-if-you-specify-max-heap-size-greater-than-available-ram), but they don't actually answer my question since I want to run more than one application which doesn't exceed the limit of memory on its own, but all together they do.

Comment: Memory leaks have nothing to do with your scenario.

Comment: If you want to do something like what you have mentioned consider having a look at a multi-tenant JVM like Waratek

Answer (score 2):

What you will experience is increased swapping during major garbage collections and thus increased GC pause-times.

When used memory exceeds physical memory (well, in fact even before that) modern OSs will write some of the less-used memory to disk. With a JVM this will most probably be some parts of the heap's tenured generation. When a major GC occurs it will have to touch all of the heap so it has to swap back in all of the pages it has offloaded to disk resulting in heavy IO-activity and increased CPU-load.

With multiple JVMs that have few major GCs this might work out with slightly increased pause times since one JVM's heap should easily fit into physical memory, but with one JVM's heap exceeding physical memory or simultaneous major GCs from several JVMs this might result in lots of swapping in and out of memory-pages ("thrashing") and GCs might take a really loooong time (up to several minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Xmx merely reserves virtual address space. And it is virtual not physic.

The response of this setting depends on the OS :

Windows : The limit is defined by swap + physical. The exception are large pages (which need to be enabled with a group policy setting), which will limit it by physical ram (XMS is not possible).

Linux behavior is more complicated. (it depends on the vm.overcommit_memory and related sysctls and various flags from the mmap syscall) can (but not all) be controlled by JVM configuration flags. The behavior can be :
- Xms can exceed total ram + swap 
- Xmx is capped by available physical ram.